# R Draws Plots with Rectangles Instead of Text

Tags: r, linux, pipeline, snakemake, singularity-container

I'm building a pipeline with `snakemake` and using `conda` and `singularity` environments to ensure reproducibility. I run into an error where the text on my plots is replaced by rectangles
[image]

After experimenting with the pipeline on Linux and Mac systems and disabling the singularity container, it appears the issue stems from a missing font library as the text is drawn normally when I only run the pipeline using only `conda` (`--use-conda`) on my Mac.

The singularity container is built from [this miniconda](https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/miniconda3) docker image that uses Debian GNU/Linux. 
I've managed to create a minimal example pipeline where the text doesn't get drawn.

```
# Snakefile
singularity: "docker://continuumio/miniconda3"

rule all:
    input:
        "mtcars-plot.png"

rule plot_mtcars:
    output:
        "mtcars-plot.png"
    conda:
        "minimal.yaml"
    script:
        "mtcars-test.R"
```

```
# mtcars-test.R
library(ggplot2)
png("mtcars-plot.png")
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + geom_boxplot()
dev.off()
```

```
# minimal.yaml
channels:
    - bioconda
    - conda-forge
    - defaults
dependencies:
    - r-base =3.6
    - r-ggplot2
```

To draw the broken plot, run the pipeline

```
snakemake --use-conda --use-singularity
```

What packages/libraries could I be missing to correctly draw text with R on Debian GNU/Linux?

Comment: Seems related to this: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/7455 Do you have fonts installed on that machine? Also seems to be discussed here: https://github.com/conda-forge/r-base-feedstock/issues/91

Comment: Thanks for the link @MrFlick the links helped fix the issue!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to MrFlick's comment, the second [link](https://github.com/conda-forge/r-base-feedstock/issues/91) says the `mscorefonts` package is needed for text support in R.

Adding `mscorefonts` to the `conda` environment fixes the issue

```
# minimal.yaml
channels:
    - bioconda
    - conda-forge
    - defaults
dependencies:
    - r-base =3.6
    - r-ggplot2
    - mscorefonts
```

Answer (score 1):

`conda config --set always_yes yes`

`conda config --add channels conda-forge`

`conda update --all`

`conda install r-ggplot2 r-rmarkdown`

Running this fixed it for me